# undefined reference to `vtable for MainWindow' error

Tags: linux, qt, qwt

hi every one i am working a in qt and qwt but in my program i am getting these error

undefined reference to `vtable for MainWindow'
error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

i didnt get it what is the meaning of these error can some one explain it as apparently i have no error in my code

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not linking to everything you should. You need to run moc on your .cpp files, and add e.g. `#include "moc_myfile.cpp"` to the *end* of `myfile.cpp`

Alternatively, you have declared a virtual function (destructor perhaps) without defining it.

Comment: thanks so much sir one more thing sir i have another same program exactly same but it didnt gave this error and didnt include moc file in my program thanks

Comment: @randy: You'll need to show the source. The two problems I mentioned are common reasons for this error. If you want more detailed help, provide more details in the question.

Comment: ok sir thanks the code is a bit lenghty i will try to figure it out my self if i get failed then i will ask . thanks so much for your help

Comment: If you're using qmake, add the .h file to the HEADERS (HEADERS += your.h) and rerun qmake. Including the .moc is usually not necessary.